# backing up SVN repository on Ubuntu linux to a Windows share

Tags: linux, ubuntu, backup, svn, restore

We have a Ubuntu(head-less) system that runs our SVN repository(ies). Would like to regularly back it up to a Windows share automatically. What should we do ? Any links/articles ? Any gotchas ?

How easy is it to restore from these backups ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$ svnadmin dump /path/to/repo | gzip > backup.gz`

`$ gunzip -c backup.gz | svnadmin load /path/to/repo`

Answer (score 1):

Tar it up, then use `gvfs-copy` to copy it over, or mount the share as CIFS, copy, and unmount.

Answer (score 1):

Further to Rajat's anwswer, if your Ubuntu system has the space I would do a hotcopy first and then either dump the hotcopy or tar it up.

```
$ svnadmin hotcopy /path/to/repo /path/to/local/backup
$ svnadmin dump /path/to/local/backup | gzip > backup.gz
  or
$ tar czf backup-hotcopy.tgz /path/to/local/backup
```

Thus,

- you have a local backup if the repo gets corrupted.
- the backup can be done without any outages - it can be done whilst dev's are commiting to the database.   (IIRC the `dump` command may not work cleanly on a live repo - but I can't find a definitive source on this after doing a quick search - someone correct me if I'm wrong or point to confirmation)
- The local hotcopy will also include any hook scripts that you may have setup - whereas the dump will not.

However, the tar'd up hotcopy contains a repository in Linux format.  This may cause issues if your Ubuntu box dies and you want to restore onto a Windows machine.  (This one bit me once - we needed to restore quickly and a windows box was the only server available).  This is not an issue with the dump variant.  You'll need to create a working reposity somewhere first - but having done so the dump can be loaded without any care as to the underlying OS.